# Best languages for designing user interfaces?

Tags: user-interface, real-time-data

I need to design a GUI which will recieve data from a micrcontroller(actually my robot, to be precise) via serial port or wireless and plot them in real time.

Which language or platform will be most appropriate  to design such interface?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java, Python, and VB are all options for standalone GUIs, among others such as C#/C++, but I'd go with one of the three listed here.

-[Python + Tkinter](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm)
-[Java](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33536/An-Introduction-to-Java-GUI-Programming)
-[Visual Basic](http://www.virtualsplat.com/tips/visual-basic-tutorials-gui.asp)

Comment: No one uses VB anymore and Java has no way of providing a native looking UI. Python could be a good choice, C++ will get you the most native cross-platform look, C# is a bit worse here but still a great choice